# Create CoreData model with default dataset

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

What is the best way to create a CoreData model with default entries, say 10 entries?

The idea coming to my mind is to first check if the entity is empty and add the objects if entity returns 0 count.

Is there any other better solution? If not, how to achieve the idea mentioned above?

Comment: if its literally only a few entries your probably best just doing it as you say, check on application launch to see if there is any data, if not create it. For larger sets you might create some classes to build out the initial data structure or even supply a base sqlite file with the required data already inside.

Comment: Even with a small data set I would **NOT** do that on launch.  If you have pre-canned data, ship it with the app 100% of the time.  Never do anything on launch that you do not absolutely need to do.  Very slippery slope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want pre-loaded data then create a SQLite file and embed it in the application.  Then on first launch, copy the file into the final location and stand up your Core Data stack.

It is easy to create the SQLite file on OS X as the structure of Core Data is identical on all platforms.